# Unable to install stable-baselines3[extra] using pip in Python 3.7

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `stable-baselines3[extra]` using  `pip install stable baselines3[extra]` but it ends up with the error mentioned below. I am using:

**User Current Version:- 3.7.13 (default, Apr 24 2022, 01:06:43)
GCC 11.2.0]**

On Ubuntu 22.04 in PyCharm as well as Jupyter Notebook. In Google Colab, it installs without any error. What might be the issue?
Here is the python version in Google Colab:

**User Current Version:- 3.7.13 (default, Apr 24 2022, 01:04:09)
[GCC 7.5.0]**
Here is the error message:

```
    Building wheels for collected packages: AutoROM.accept-rom-license
  Building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: '/home/jamshaid/PycharmProjects/Edge Caching using stable-baselines3/virtualenv/bin/python' '/home/jamshaid/PycharmProjects/Edge Caching using stable-baselines3/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py' build_wheel /tmp/tmpp4hjhtme
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o4p_ksow/autorom-accept-rom-license_8ed43d51fff74c73944a3a9f954d2153
  Complete output (62 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running install
  running install_egg_info
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/jamshaid/PycharmProjects/Edge Caching using stable-baselines3/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/jamshaid/PycharmProjects/Edge Caching using stable-baselines3/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/jamshaid/PycharmProjects/Edge Caching using stable-baselines3/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 262, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 231, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
      cmdclass={"install": InstallCommand},
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 335, in run
      self.run_command('install')
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 8, in run
      super().run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
      return orig.install.run(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 622, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_egg_info.py", line 26, in finalize_options
      ('install_dir', 'install_dir'))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 287, in set_undefined_options
      src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
      self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
      setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
      raise AttributeError(attr)
  AttributeError: install_layout
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for AutoROM.accept-rom-license
Failed to build AutoROM.accept-rom-license
ERROR: Could not build wheels for AutoROM.accept-rom-license, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```